# SQFLITE database location IOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to save a file from my application the the "My Files" folder on IOS.

I have added the following three entries in the info.plist file

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

Once I do the above then my file do get saved but also my Database files that is created.
Without it I seem not to be able to save the file to the folder.
It seems to be the "UIFileSharingEnabled" entry that causes this behaviour.

I created a Database helper file to create my database file in, using the following code to get the location to store the database

```
final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath); 

return await sql.openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate,
    onUpgrade: _onUpgrade
    );
```

Currently it crates the files in the "MY Files" folder of IOS where it is visible for all the users.

What is the best way to hide the database files like Android that does not displays the files for the users.

I tried to use "getLibraryDirectory" but it only saves the files in sub folders in the "My Files" locations.

What will be the best approach to create the database and hide it from the users.

Will the assets folder be the best bet?